# cURL Login with PHP

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I've looked for how to use cURL with PHP but in all the examples, it asks for post information. In the destination site which I want to login, it has these headers. Is there any way to login with cURL to this site?

> POST //Login.aspx?t=tAagdOpCKVbBZJICqxicOwGO3g5%2fDqQ9HvthBEckSU%2fRd5lEPDasJELARgr2txnB12tfPnVvJSF1BasxQhlzbQ%3d%3d HTTP/1.1
>   Host: awebsite.com
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Cookie: __qca=P0-1236052332-1411314388865; ASP.NET_SessionId=2lhdwlfafvc4mrt1leqofp4p; __utma=219632280.2029473779.1403506413.1419763928.1419764926.556; __utmc=219632280; __utmz=219632280.1419764926.556.7.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utma=94244052.918496071.1403626522.1419678978.1419763934.203; __utmb=94244052.500.10.1419763934; __utmc=94244052; __utmz=94244052.1419763934.203.181.utmcsr=awebsite.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
>   Origin: http://awebsite.com
>   Referer: http://awebsite.com/Default.aspx
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

Comment: @KevinBrown, unfortunately no. As you can see in the headers, there are no username and password field for sending. Only "t" and some encoded things.

Comment: can you please copy each header line on one line please, it's hard to read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is: `http://awebsite.com/Login.aspx?t=tAagdOpCKVbBZJICqxicOwGO3g5%2fDqQ9HvthBEckSU%2fRd5lEPDasJELARgr2txnB12tfPnVvJSF1BasxQhlzbQ%3d%3d`

There is no post data. There are cookies and a content-type. Some APIs I've used reject the request if the content type is not x-www-form-urlencoded, but those google analysis cookies are likely unnecessary.

Check out the cURL doc of the setopt function.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php

If you try to test the request you can also use curl from the bash.

Comment: Isn't "t" variable on the link is a post data? I'm trying to understand it but haven't figured out yet.

Comment: No, it's also the query string, because the POST starts after the blank line, like:
POST /anypath?with&any=param HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 24

postBegins=here&isUrlencoded=true